# CakePHP - I can not access $ this-> Auth-> user () data after the login

Tags: cakephp

This is my AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array('Auth');

public function beforeFilter() { 

//Set up Auth Component
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'CmsUser';
        $this->Auth->authenticate ='Form';
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password');
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'admin_cms_users', 'action' => 'login','admin' => true);
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'admin_cms_helps', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';
        $this->Auth->loginError = 'Pogrešno korisničko ime/lozinka. Pokušajte ponovo!';
        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false; // najvažnija postavka za redirekciju
    $this->Auth->allow('display');
        // Additional criteria for loging.
        $this->Auth->userScope = array('CmsUser.active' => 1); //user needs to be active.

}
```

This is my AdminCmsUsersController:

```
class AdminCmsUsersController extends AppController {

    public $name = 'AdminCmsUsers';
    public $uses = array('CmsUser'); 

public function beforeFilter(){
parent::beforeFilter();
}

.
.
.
.
public function admin_login() {
$this->layout='cms_main';
if($this->request->is('post') AND $this->Auth->login($this->request->data)){
$this->CmsUser->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
print_r($this->Auth->user());
print_r($this->Session->read());
$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
}

}
.
.
.
```

print_r($this->Auth->user()) result:

```
Array
(
    [CmsUser] => Array
        (
            [username] => someuser
            [password] => somepass
        )

)
```

//print_r($this->Session->read()) results:

```
    [Auth] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [CmsUser] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => lupus10
                            [password] => canis10
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

My user has a name, email, and other data. Why can not access this data?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of

```
$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password');
```

in your AppController, and

```
$this->CmsUser->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

should probably be

```
$this->CmsUser->id = $this->Auth->user('CmsUser.id');
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure Auth component is loaded in AppController

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Authentication Cakephp Cookbook- 2.x Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) mentioned:

> Be sure to manually add the new User id to the array passed to the login method. Otherwise you won’t have the user id available.

Below is how I deal with it in my project:

```
    public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this_user = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('email_address' => $this->request->data['User']['email_address'])
        ));
        $user_id = $this_user['User']['user_id'];
        $this->request->data['User'] = array_merge(
                $this->request->data['User'],
                array('user_id' => $user_id)
        );
        if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data['User'])) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to use $this->Auth->user('id') in other controllers. (in my case, it's $this->Auth->user('user_id') )